# cast byte array pointer to int array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a pointer to an array of bytes (u8). I now have a function that takes a pointer of type int (unsigned int). What is an elegant way to accomplish this without creating a new array and converting each element?

I need to convert each byte to a single int. 
(i.e. {0x12, 0x34, 0x56} --> {0x00000012, 0x00000034, 0x00000056})

```
void external_function(unsigned int *val, int length)
{
    //Write values to ...
}

void my_function(u8 *array)
{
    int length = 10;

    //Need to convert *array to (unsigned int *)
    external_function(array, length);
}
```

Comment: C will do this for you if you do `array[0] = input[0]` and so on.

Comment: If `external_function` does not require all data in one call, you can do this without an array of `int` by defining a single `int` and iteratively assigning to it one value from the byte array and passing the address of the `int` to `external_function` with a length of one `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is an elegant way to accomplish this without creating a new array and converting each element?

There's not one. That's how you have to do it. The problem is that the `00` bytes between the elements you need just aren't there while it's a `byte` array.

Comment: The reason why this is impossible is because memory layout, including the size, of the array element type  is part of the binary interface of `external_function`.